# Changing permalinks via functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I have designed a **wordpress theme** where I have designed a separate page for users to log in and this page will be accessible if **permalinks** are selected as **%pagename% %category%**.

For this, I know that I have to select the permanent link I want through the WordPress settings and from the unique links tab.

But I want to put a piece of code inside the `functions.php` file so that it will be done automatically after the user activates the WordPress theme and the previously selected links will be disabled.

I have used the following code but it did not change the permalink:

```
/*
 * Set permlinks on theme activate
 */
    function set_custom_permalinks() {
        $current_setting = get_option('permalink_structure');

        // Save permalinks to a custom setting, force create of rules file
        global $wp_rewrite;
        update_option("rewrite_rules", FALSE);
        $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%postname%/%category%/');
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);
    }
    add_action('after_switch_theme', 'set_custom_permalinks');
```

---

**Edit:**

After a bit of searching, I found out that permalinks can be edited through the database in addition to the WordPress settings.

To change the permanent links through the database, I went to the following path:

**1-** I clicked on `wp_options` in the database

**2-** Under `option_name`, I looked for the `permalink_structure` table.

**3-** After finding the `permalink_structure` table, I clicked on the **edit** option.

**4-** Then in the `option_value` field, I entered my permanent link as follows:

```
/%postname%/%category%/
```

After completing the above steps, the permanent link of my site was changed correctly.

Now I want a code that can do this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved what I wanted by using the following code and my site's permalinks were sorted correctly:

```
function custom_permalinks() {
   global $wp_rewrite; 
    
$wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%postname%/%category%/'); 

update_option( "rewrite_rules", FALSE ); 

$wp_rewrite->flush_rules( true );
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_permalinks' );
```

By placing the above code in the `functions.php` file, the site's permanent links will be arranged as you wish, and the **user** cannot change your permanent link through the **WordPress settings** under any circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code; it will hopefully work:

```
function set_custom_permalinks() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    // Define your custom permalink structure here
    $custom_permalink_structure = '/%postname%/%category%/';

    // Save permalinks to a custom setting
    update_option('permalink_structure', $custom_permalink_structure);

    // Flush and regenerate rewrite rules
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure($custom_permalink_structure);
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);
}
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'set_custom_permalinks');
```